# PHP mysql query ignores POST vars

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to move vars from js code to php so I can do a query. I know for sure that the vars are getting to the PHP fine.

The problem is, when I'm trying to combine the vars in the SQL query, it ignores them and I'm not getting any results...

Here is the problematic part of the code:

```
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $request = json_decode($postdata);

    $gluten = $_POST['gluten'];
    $vegan = $_POST['vegan'];
    $vegetarian = $_POST['vegetarian'];

     $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM dishes JOIN restaurants USING (res_id)
                   WHERE (gluten LIKE '$gluten' AND '$vegan' LIKE 0 AND vegetarian LIKE '$vegetarian')");
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: From Where POST vars are coming??

Comment: Can you do a print_r($_POST) and check the variables are actually there?

Comment: you are vulnerable to SQL injection.  you should be using placeholders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get your POST vars correctly in your php file,

Do query like this.

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM dishes JOIN restaurants using (res_id) WHERE (gluten LIKE '%".$gluten."%' AND '".$vegan."' LIKE 0 AND vegetarian LIKE '%".$vegetarian."%')");
```